# find all positive integers that are the cube of the sum of their digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility, diophantine-equations

> (HMMT 2000 Guts #5). Find all positive integers that are the cube of the sum of their digits.

> I've found a (very) tedious way to resolve the question described below. The tedious part is highlighted in a similar way to the question at the top.

Suppose n is such a number. Note that the sum of the digits of a number is congruent to its remainder modulo 9. So $n^3 \equiv n \mod 9,$ which implies $n\equiv 0,1,-1\mod 9.$ If n has a single digit, then $n=n^3,$ so $n=1$ as $n>0.$  $ n$ is a perfect cube, and the only two digit perfect cubes are $27$ and $64,$ neither of which work, so there are no two-digit solutions. The only three digit perfect cubes are $125,216,343,512,729.$ But $(1+2+5)^3 > 125, (2+1+6)^3 > 216, (3+4+3)^3 > 343, (5+1+2)^3 = 512, (7+2+9)^3 > 729.$ Hence the only three-digit solution is $512.$

> Now my question is, is there a better way to solve this question than to literally check all 4 to 6 digit cubes?

Note that there are no solutions with $7$ or more digits, as the largest such number would be $(9\cdot 7)^3 = 250047 < 10^6.$

Comment: I don't know if there is a better solution but meanwhile, that $n$ is $6$-digit or less means $n < 100$, and then that and the additional constraint that $n$ must also satisfy $n \equiv -1,1,0 \mod 9$ [one of these $3$ possibilities] leaves you with only about $30$ choices....

Comment: Say beginning digit is $a$ and total you have $n$ digits with $4\leq n\leq 6$. Then, $10^{n-1}a < (a+9(n-1))^3.$ For $n = 6,$ this already rules out everything if you plot the cubic. For $n = 4,5$ this does not really help.

Comment: but $n = 4,5$ cases are definitely easily checkable by hand with the modulo by $9$ restriction.

Comment: @Mike I think you made a typo when you said "... that n is 6-digit or less means $n<100$."

Comment: @user33096 Yes you're right I did make a mistake there...I should have said that $n$ is the *cube* of an integer less than $100$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=k^3.$  If $n$ has $6$ digits, the largest it could be is $(6\cdot 9)^3 = 157464$, which shows that one digit must be $1$.  So in fact the largest it could be is $(1+5\cdot 9)^3 = 97336$ which is too small.  So there are no $6$ digit (or larger)  solutions.  (I think this is the gist of @dezdichado's comment.)

Because the cube root of $100,000 = 46.4\ldots$, we know that $k\leq 46.$  Using your observation that $k\equiv -1, 0, 1 \pmod{9}$ leaves us with only these $16$ possibilities for $k$:

$$1, 8, 9, 10, 17, 18, 19, 26, 27, 28, 35, 36, 37, 44, 45, 46.$$

We can just check these or we can play a bit more:

Since $(5\cdot 9)^3 = 91125$, we see that a $5$-digit solution must have at least one non-$9$ digit.  Since $(4\cdot 9+8)^3 = 85184$, the largest the first two digits can be is $79$, so at least one digit is at most $7$.  Since $4\cdot 9 +7 = 43$ we can cross off the last three numbers from the list.

Of these, $1, 8, 17, 18, 26, 27$ work.

A couple of observations:  It surprises me that the last two pairs are consecutive, and both are of the shape $-1, 0 \pmod{9}$ so I feel like I've missed something.  Since $1$ is a solution, it doesn't seem like modular considerations would eliminate $1 \pmod{9}$.

Comment: If you think answerers are talking down to you, then it might be the lack of context in your question.   We just have to guess what level you're at, unless you give us some clues.